# How to multiply time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following timespan coming from a model in MVC:

```
timeTaken = "00:01:00";
```

Then I have a multiplier

```
 multiply = "3";
```

Result: 00:03:00

What would be the best way to calculate this time?

I don't know a great deal of libraries. I was thinking of splitting the seconds, minutes and hours, dividing each one into seconds, multiplying then putting it back together.

However, I have this kind of calculations for many sections, it just seems a little mundane. Can I just multiply the time in a better manner?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say get the total milliseconds from the `TimeSpan`, multiply that in your JS and convert it to whatever granularity you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am combining the snippets I found in multiple pages. Conversion of hh:mm:ss to seconds, multiply 3x and then again convert to hh:mm:ss.

```
var hms = '00:01:00';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 
var newSeconds= 3*seconds;

// multiply by 1000 because Date() requires miliseconds
var date = new Date(newSeconds * 1000);
var hh = date.getUTCHours();
var mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
var ss = date.getSeconds();
// If you were building a timestamp instead of a duration, you would uncomment the following line to get 12-hour (not 24) time
// if (hh > 12) {hh = hh % 12;}
// These lines ensure you have two-digits
if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}
if (ss < 10) {ss = "0"+ss;}
// This formats your string to HH:MM:SS
var t = hh+":"+mm+":"+ss;
document.write(t);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/o5rf3Lws/)

Answer (score 3):

First you can convert them to seconds as below

```
var hms = "00:01:00";
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 

var newSeconds=seconds * 3;

var t = new Date();
t.setSeconds(newSeconds);

console.log(t);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lqckkoj/1/)**

**Update**

To just obtain time do as below

```
var time=t.toTimeString().split(' ')[0]
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lqckkoj/2/)**

**UPDATE**

To obtain just hour from time you can do as follows

```
t.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]
```

and to obtain hour in 12 hour format you can do as below:

```
 var hour;
if(t.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]>12)
    hour=t.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]-12;
else
    hour=t.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].split(':')[0];
alert(hour);
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lqckkoj/3/)**

Comment: This is a great way of doing it, how do I write out just the time and not the rest?

Comment: @Gurupeasad Rao Thanks. After some testing, it's not very accurate. It's off by a few minutes. And is there a way to omit the hour preceded by the new time?

Comment: `t.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]` This will do.. May I know how it is not accurate in your case? What is the actual time you feed?

Comment: Updated answer with demo! check it.

Comment: Sure, in your demo, the sum is added to the current time as the new Date() object is initialised. The output I require is 00:03:00, yours is current time + 3mins, so 13:29:00 locally and your updated version is just 1. Hope that helps and thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Yea I agree!! sorry for that!! anyways you have your answer and even that one is good!! just got confused with minor part!! :) Happy coding.. :)